# Angular 5 Pipe - replace entity id with name

Tags: angular, caching, pipe, observable, angular5

I need to convert category ID to its name in Angular 5 component using pipe - im giving my pipe code below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesResourceService } from '../apiResources/categories-resource.service';
import { Category } from '../models/category.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http/src/client';

@Pipe({ name: 'categoryPipe', pure: false })
@Injectable()
export class CategoryNamePipe implements PipeTransform {

  private cachedData: Category[];

  constructor(private http: CategoriesResourceService) { }

  transform(value: number): any {

    if (this.cachedData != null) {
      return this.findCachedItemById(value);
    }

    this.http.get(null)
      .map(result => result)
      .subscribe(result => this.cachedData = result);

    return this.findCachedItemById(value);
  }

  findCachedItemById(value: number) {
    if (this.cachedData == null || this.cachedData.length === 0) { return ''; }
    for (const item of this.cachedData) {
      if (item.categoryId === value) {
        return item.name;
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
}
```

And use it in component like below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks">           
    <td>{{task.categoryId | categoryPipe}} - {{task.subcategoryId  | categoryPipe}}</td>
</tr>
```

I want to achieve that i pass category ID into pipe and it fetches the category from API (from database) and returns its name - even if its not in cachedData, then only take it from cachedData and dont send API request.

My problem is that im not able to cache data, its sending like 200 HTTP requests to categories API for 5 usages of this pipe (5 rows of table).

Could you please give me some suggestion how to do it or help me with fixing my code?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Don't make an HTTP call in your pipe.

Rather, make your HTTP call in your app component once (the will be launched when the app starts), and store your data however you want (localStorage, custom service ...).

Once you have it, let's say in a service, the pipe becomes easy to use :

```js
transform(value: number): any {

  if (!this.myService.cachedData) { return 'Data is not cached (put your own message there)'; }

  return this.myService.cachedData.find(item => item.categoryId === value) ?
    this.myService.cachedData.find(item => item.categoryId === value).name :
    'No cached data found (put your own message there)';
}
```